# react hook form, A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

i have a problem with use onChange method inside a Controller tag from react-hook-form. I need capture when the user select a field to render a new one downside, with information relationship in the last one.
Im using react-hook-form with MUI

```
                <FormControl>
                      <InputLabel>Universidad</InputLabel>

                      <Controller
                        as={
                          <Select placeholder="Universidad">
                            {universities.map((item, i) => {
                              return (
                                <MenuItem value={item.value} key={i}>
                                  {item.label}
                                </MenuItem>
                              );
                            })}
                          </Select>
                        }
                        name="university"
                        control={control}
                        onChange={([event]) => {
                          console.log(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue=""
                      />
                    </FormControl>
```

Comment: you have seem this? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem. I tried to work with the onChange event on the <Select> but that didn't work.

Comment: i can get a parcial solution for this. i share the gist of the code for you. - https://gist.github.com/Yegaston/0554b580d0fc28e226721e630626f938
have the follow bug.
When you select one, the next one appears, but the previous one does not show the selected option, but nevertheless the new one took care considering it
@Reggi